# NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAnalytics! Angular 8

Tags: angular, firebase, webpack, firebase-analytics

When run 'npm test', I receive this error:

NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ComparePageComponent -> AngularFireAnalytics]:
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ComparePageComponent -> AngularFireAnalytics]:
            NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAnalytics!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'ComparePageComponent', Function ] })

> app.module.ts

```
import {AngularFireModule} from "@angular/fire";
import {AngularFireAnalyticsModule, AngularFireAnalytics} from "@angular/fire/analytics";

@NgModule({
   imports: [
   .....
       AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
       AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
   ],
   providers: [
      AngularFireAnalytics,
      ...fromServices.services,
   ],
```

> firebase.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAnalytics } from "@angular/fire/analytics";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FirebaseService {

    constructor(private analytics: AngularFireAnalytics) {}

      public logEvent(eventName: string, params: {}) {

          this.analytics.logEvent(eventName, params).then( res => {
             console.log('event registered', eventName, params);
          })
          .catch(error => {
             console.log('error', error.message);
          });
      }
}
```

> compare-page.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseService} from "../../../services/firebase.service";

export class ComparePageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
     this.firebaseService.logEvent('test', {});
}
```

**Do you have any idea what's missing?**

I used this tutorial: https://www.positronx.io/firebase-authentication-in-angular-8-with-angularfire2/

Comment: you need to include `AngularFireAnalyticsModule` in `ComparePageComponent` module, so it will be available when Depency injection resolve the instances, moreover, you should mock the `FirebaseService` in `ComparePageComponent` module then `AngularFireAnalyticsModule` won't be dependency anymore

Answer (score 2):

There is no provider called `AngularFireAnalytics`. Therefore you need to change the `providers` array to the following:

```
  providers: [
      ...fromServices.services,
   ],
```

Then to use firebase analytics do the following in the component:

```
import { AngularFireAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

constructor(analytics: AngularFireAnalytics) {
  analytics.logEvent('custom_event', { ... });
}
```

Check here :

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/analytics/getting-started.md

Comment: It's the same error if I delete 'AngularFireAnalytics' from the providers.

Comment: What is this `fromServices.services`?

Comment: Another services:

Comment: import { IpcService } from './ipc.service';
    import { SyncService } from './sync.service';
    import { AppSettingsService } from './app-settings.service';
    import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';

    export const services: any[] = [IpcService, SyncService, AppSettingsService, 
    FirebaseService];

    export * from './ipc.service';
    export * from './sync.service';
    export * from './app-settings.service';
    export * from './firebase.service';

Comment: Are u using the latest version of angularfire? Because it seems AngularFireAnalytics was added 9 days ago but for sure it's not a provider

Comment: I have the latest version

Comment: I just created a new ionic project and add the angularfireanalytics as said in the documenation and didnt have any problem

Comment: The problem was from my test file. I added a mock service and now all is ok. For example, in products.service,spec.ts,  describe('ProductsService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      providers: [
        ProductsService,
        {provide: AngularFireAnalytics, useClass: FirebaseMockService}
      ],
    });
  });

Comment: Okay please upvote this answer and mark it as correct since it helped you thank you!